# Maven/Eclipse/Android upgrading API version

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

We have been using Android API version 17 in a project and wish to upgrade to API version 19 because the application runs on Android 4.4.

We use Maven as our build environment.  I have replaced all the occurrences of SDK version 17 to 19 in our `AndroidManifest.xml`.  But I am having problems upgrading to the 4.4 platform through Maven.

I used the Android SDK Deployer tool to push the android-4.4 package into my local Maven repository.  I then replaced the reference to android-4.2 to android-4.4 in our 'parent' POM.xml:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- <groupId>com.google.android</groupId> OLD -->
            <groupId>android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>4.2.2_r2</version> OLD -->
            <version>4.4.2_r4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

This change seemed to introduce a conflict.  Another dependency is bringing in version `2.1_r1` of android package which is conflicting with the new `4.4.2_r4` package:

```
Excerpt from 'mvn dependency:tree':
.
[INFO] +- com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:jar:1.0.10-2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.tony19:apktool-lib:jar:1.4.4-3:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.android:android:jar:2.1_r1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.khronos:opengl-api:jar:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1:compile
[INFO] |        +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |        \- xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.4c:compile
```

I noticed that if I move the `<dependency>` declaration of the 4.4 package above the logback-android-classic dependency declaration in `pom.xml` then our module will use the 4.4 dependency.  However I don't think this is a proper fix, and I am running into various issues building the project as a whole.

Can those more experienced with Maven please advise on the correct way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through each affected module and adding an exclusion to the logback-android-classic dependency seems to have resolved it:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <groupId>android</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```